# What does 'WWAN-HW missing' mean?

Tags: wireless, xubuntu

I am trying to find a solution to my "wifi-disabled" problem... I've been googling and reading and found this command:

```
nmcli general
STATE      CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI      WWAN-HW  WWAN    
connected  full          enabled  disabled  missing  enable
```

What is "missing", what is WWAN-HM?

Comment: WWAN-HW = Wireless WAN Hardware (= cellular modem)

Comment: What about results for `rfkill list all`

Comment: ```rfkill list all
0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no```

Answer (score 2):

`WWAN-HW` is "**W**ireless **WAN** **H**ard**w**are", and it refers to a physical cellular modem used to connect to cellular networks. `missing` indicates that such a piece of physical hardware is not connected to the computer at all, even though it is `enabled` in software (which only becomes relevant if you connect such a device later).

Comment: Thank you... I need to find a way to fix this issue that is preventing my laptop from enabling wifi, ever since I upgraded from 22.04 to 22.10 (Xubuntu) What keeps me thinking about this issue is that it's been some days with this problem, and there's been a couple of them when everything would work (wifi enabled and connected, and also bluetooth). So I don't understand why it is disabled most of the times but not all of the times.

Comment: If you have a question about fixing your WiFi, that is a different question altogether, so you can [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with all the details and maybe someone can help.

Comment: I have already asked twice.